# How to change default port for Aurelia Project

Tags: aurelia

By default, the Aurelia framework runs on port 8080.

How can you change this default port?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the port number in `aurelia.json`:

```
"platform": { 
  "id": "web", 
  "displayName": "Web", 
  "port": 6060, // <-- 
  "hmr": false, 
  "open": false, 
  "output": "dist" 
}
```

Comment: I only know of changing this in `webpack.config.js` for webpack, or in `run.ts` for aurelia-cli. It would be helpful if you specified for which exact build configuration this applies (typescript/javascript? aurelia-cli/webpack?). I've never actually seen an `aurelia.js` myself..

Comment: Perhaps you meant `aurelia.json`?

Comment: @Fred, i am using current version

Comment: @Vijay "current version" doesn't mean anything to people who are reading this in the future. And that still doesn't answer the question of which build configuration you're using. Apart from that you can't change the port number in aurelia.json. So I'm sorry to say this, but apart from being unclear, this answer is also plain wrong wrong no.

Comment: @ Fred, if you feel that you are doing right thing you dont need to be sorry. I hope you have not thought, 'why i did mention latest version', this particular is available in all 2 -3 version which downloaded and used. What gives you make it '-1', perhaps you should think twice before. Why dont we change the port number from aurelia.json? what do mean to ask question, 1. We are not supposed to change or 2. you are unable to find the file aurelia.json in aurelia project to change the port. Hope you better read clearly and comment and do so. Dont misuse the privileges you have.

Comment: can you pls take back your wrong value giving '-1' ? That helps many.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your project folder, you can see a folder with name "aurelia_project". Inside that you will see "aurelia.json". There you can edit the port. Hope this clarifies.